# Library for converting between python objects and JSON data structures

Tags: python, json, introspection

I need to work in an environment where the server has data objects cached in memory, and some or all of them needs to be sent over a websocket to a client. The conversion between the objects and the data structures is very straingforward. For example, here is a TypeScript definition of a data transfer object:

```
export interface IFieldStruct {
    field_name: string;
    type: string;
    displaylabel: string;
    notnull: boolean;
}
```

The corresponding Python objects looks like this:

```
class FieldStuct:
    def __init__(field_name: str, type: str, displaylabel: str, notnull: bool):
        self.field_name = field_name
        self.field_name = field_name
        self.displaylabel = displaylabel
        self.notnull = notnull
```

Actually, the Python objects on the server side are smarter than that. They also have methods, and they also have some attributes that need not to be exported to JSON. Some of their attributes can be lists and dictionaries containing other smart objects.

Here is the problem. I would like to take advantage of code completion and code inspection in my Python IDE (pycharm). So I don't want to store this data as a data structure in Python. But I also want to be able to convert and send these objects easily.

I know that I could write my own serializer/deserializer for this. But there will be hundreds of data object classes, and I do not want to write a serializer manually. I wonder if there is good a library that already does this for me with object introspection? I do not want to reinvent the wheel. There are too many libs on PyPi, and I'm not able to find the right one. I'm not asking for opinions, I'm just asking for a list of the most popular libs that can help me in the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Pickle is one of the most popular (de)serializations libs out there, if not the most popular.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Comment: Yes, but it serializes whole objects trees into a Python specific format. The question was about to convert objects to JSON data structures.

Comment: I have changed the title a bit accordingly.